# C одного сервера,передать php файл на другой сервер, для исполнения на клиенте

Tags: php, curl, php7, wget

Два Сервера на Debian(Slave and Master)

На нем логика и база данных.

Мы скидываем файл конфига клиентам,они, грузят себе в директорию и он выполняется при загрузки страниц.

Проблема в том, что я был мало опытный, то сервер положу,то базу, то поняли что такой сервер слабый,надо мощнее. А клиентам скидываем новые конфиги, что раздражает их. И кривые ручки не всегда могут правильно вставить.

Решили что конфиг подгружать с сервака нашего, что-бы не раздражать постоянными изменениями.
Пробовал

file_get_contents(http:\),пролема,что он присылает уже результат а не сам скрыпт.

include возможен у кого сервера с полным контролем,что бы поменяли php.ini,бо отказывает в доступе.

curl,я подгружать буду файл тоже c curl,упадет скорость загрузки сайта.
Подскажите,как мне с сервака подрузить файл, что бы он исполнялся на клиенте.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не надо такого делать. Это не безопасно. Я бы рекомендовал передавать все в виде JSON. А уже на сервере принимать данные, декодировать их и сохранять результат в конфигурацию. Для удобного экспорта php-массива в файлы Вам пригодится `var_export()`